# Warning: require(/var/www/vendor/autoload.php):

Tags: laravel, docker, ubuntu, composer-php

I am good with API creation but not so good when it comes to set up the system, I was trying to learn setting laravel with docker and was referring:
https://medium.com/@shakyShane/laravel-docker-part-1-setup-for-development-e3daaefaf3c

I followed all the steps correctly but on running:

```
docker-compose exec app php artisan key:generate
```

I am getting error:

```
Warning: require(/var/www/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/artisan on line 18

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /var/www/artisan on line 18
```

Am I wrong to assume that this problem is because the composer hasn't run!!

My Project folder is in Desktop

my docker-compose.yml is written like:

```
  # The Application
  `app:`
    `build:`
      `context: ./`
      `dockerfile: app.dockerfile`
    `working_dir: /var/www`
   `volumes:`
      `- ./:/var/www``
   ` environment:`
      `- "DB_PORT=3306"`
      `- "DB_HOST=database"`

  # The Web Server
  `web:`
    `build:`
      `context: ./`
      `dockerfile: web.dockerfile`
    `working_dir: /var/www`
    `volumes_from:`
      `- app`
    `ports:`
      `- 8080:80`
```

I checked other solutions on the web but I couldn't quite understand how I need to do.

Comment: check what do you have in .`/` and if the files really in `/var/www`

Comment: @LinPy there is nothing in /var/www ,
I guess its for docker thats what I think after going through tutorial, but I guess I can be wrong, So do I have to move my complete project under /var/www

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not a good idea to follow the steps provided in the website since the

`composer` image is [DEPRECATED](https://hub.docker.com/r/composer/composer/)

you must use the newest one from [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer)

Comment: Yes I tried that command as well and it gave me error:
`Composer could not find a composer.json file in /app`

when composer.json file is already there.

Comment: the entire steps are out of date they are from 2017, try to follow some newer article or as I said in the comments start debugging your volumes , what do you mount really  from `./`

Comment: Yes True, I am already trying with PHP 7.2 it gave mcrypt error which resolved , I am sure will resolve this one as well.
But as you suggested will check for other tutorials as well.

Comment: I have one last doubt consider I added a package in composer.json  we execute command
`composer update`
How to do the same for docker app!?

Comment: in the build stage you need a `RUN` steps . if the container already running you need to use `docker exec CONATINER COMMAND`

Comment: Thank You. I am closing the issue and voted for your answer as it is the one closest.